# remove spaces between word in a sentence (Not a single input word)

Tags: javascript, regex, string, whitespace, str-replace

We have a list of words that sometimes the users or the system injects "space" in between letter, e.g. "happy" would sometimes input as "h appy" or "h a p py" or "ha p p y".

What is the best method to remove the spaces in the list of words, such as "happy" above? The words are in a sentence, e.g. "I feel hap py today." I only need to correct those key words in a list and not the whole sentence.

This is NOT the same question as removing white-space from a single word.

Comment: in which language?

Comment: The input is always a single word ?

Comment: The input is a sentence and not a single word.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you're using a html form to get the data and can use javascript to manipulate it.

Use this code to remove spaces from the entered text:

```
var str = "h a p p y";
str = str.replace(/ +/g, "");
```

Comment: Wont work for the input : I feel hap py today. ;) Read Again

Comment: thanks, but it would not work if the word(s) are in a sentence.

Comment: ofcourse it won't work for sentence, your original post was about word happy only :( please +1 the answer at least :D

Comment: we need to use dictionary api for that

Comment: thanks, but I'm not sure what you mean. I have the list of 30 words that we want to clean. I am looking for cleaning up the entire sentence.

Comment: I can help you code it thought, not simple to ans it here i guess, btw plz upvote the answer if it was near to your query at least